# Juno 5.0 beta Skype mic muted again after sound mixer system update

Tags: sound, skype

Skype is again muted after the update of the sound mixer package (I think switchboard-plug-locale), mic is muted for an unknown reason, MBP 6,1. Before it was working fine, and even better than under MacOS in Juno (while it is muted in Loki).

Any suggestions?

Comment: Latest Skype update (version Skype 8.26.0.70) doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: Since installing Juno 5.0 (not the beta), I don't have the issue anymore, problem solved that way.